# Where is data stored when deploying RShiny app via shinyapp.io?

Tags: r, shiny, privacy, shinyapps, data-storage

I have built an RShiny app where I use a dataset so that the app can display plots. I have a privacy question about deploying this app. When I deploy the app via shinyapps.io, is the dataset then saved on an RShiny server? Or does it use the local datafile? If the latter is the case, should my computer be active then 24/7 for the app to work?

Comment: Everything in the app folder will be copied to shinyapps.io

Comment: I agree with @PorkChop.  Also, remember that any data *created* by users of the app will not persist on shinyapps.io. shinyapps.io is containerised.  To persist user-created data between invocations of the app, you will need to either download then upload each time or use a third party storage solution such as AWS.

Comment: And how is the security managed of shinyapps.io? Is it GDPR acceptable? The ethical committee of my insittute is cautious with storing data on external servers for the sake of security and privacy.. It is hard to find more information on how the data is protected in shinyapps.io...

Comment: rstudio has `GDPR` guidelines published https://www.rstudio.com/about/rstudio-and-the-gdpr-what-you-need-to-know/. But as far as i know `shinyapps.io` will copy the data to the US servers unless its otherwise specified